# Fail to Link Boost in CMAKE

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

Here is my CMakeList.text :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project(project)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

FIND_PACKAGE(Boost 1.66 REQUIRED date_time program_options thread filesystem system unit_test_framework)
IF(${Boost_FOUND})
    INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})
ENDIF()

add_executable(project main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(project ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

It configures well and according to the output info it did find where the boost is.

However, when I tried to run my program, it shows the error :

```
gmake[3]: *** No rule to make target '/usr/include/_ansi.h', needed by 'CMakeFiles/project.dir/main.cpp.o'.  Stop.
gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:76: CMakeFiles/project.dir/all] Error 2
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:83: CMakeFiles/project.dir/rule] Error 2
gmake: *** [Makefile:118: project] Error 2
```

where `_ansi.h` is the first header file in my `/usr/include/` and boost is also located at `/usr/include/boost`. I have checked that the file does exist and if I removed it, it would say `no rule to make target on {the second header file}`.

Any idea how to fix this ?

Comment: What is content of `Boost_INCLUDE_DIR` and `Boost_LIBRARIES` variables used in your code? (I know these variables are set by `find_package(Boost)`, but their actual content may shed a light on the problem).

Answer (score 0):

This snipped is adapted directly from the [official documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.12/module/FindBoost.html):

```
find_package(Boost 1.66 REQUIRED COMPONENTS date_time program_options thread filesystem system unit_test_framework)
if (Boost_FOUND)
    add_executable(pro main.cpp)
    target_link_libraries(pro Boost::date_time Boost::program_options Boost::thread Boost::filesystem Boost::system Boost::unit_test_framework)
endif()
```